# How launch thread with function of different calling convention

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, publish-subscribe, calling-convention

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602568/how-to-use-lambda-functions-with-boostbind-stdbind-in-vc-2010), I've a pure virtual class:

```
#define CALL __stdcall
class IIEvent
{
    virtual ~IIEvent() {}

    virtual void CALL ev1(int) = 0;
    virtual void CALL ev2(int) = 0;
};
```

This interface is used to implement a publish-subscriber pattern. The library calls `IIEvent` function in a separate thread.

```
void generateEvent1( int i )
{
    // mListeners is a std::vector< IIEvent* >
    for ( auto& f : mListeners )
    {
        std::thread t( &IIOEvent::ev1, f, t ) );
        t.detach();
    }
}
```

But this gives me compile time error (I'm using MinGW in this case): the problem seems the calling convention. If I remove calling convention all works fine.

So how can I launch a thread of a function with some specific calling convention?

**Note:** need calling convention here to be sure that library works with other compilers.

Thanks to Cory Nelson a solution can be:

```
void generateEvent1( int i )
{
    // mListeners is a std::vector< IIEvent* >
    for ( auto& f : mListeners )
    {
        std::thread t( [f, i] ()
        {
            f->ev1( b );
        });
        t.detach();
    }
}
```

But this seems causing run-time crash to my application...

Comment: `std::thread` accepts a functor. Try wrapping your function in a lambda.

Comment: What's `b` and `t`? Are they somehow related to `i`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I've corrected it: `std::thread t( [&f, i] ()` where `i` is the param of ev1.